# How can I populate my second combobox based on other combobox selected item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, grid

My Question is i want to see my artist combobox selected artist related albums in my albums combobox.

I found out code example on this site and it is similar to my problem:

but I didn't understand how we get the SelectedArtist value. I pluged this code and test it it keeps giving me null ... I tried to assign artistName to SelectedArtist from the lists of Artits I have but that wasn't successfull:

Can some one help me how i can find the SelectedArtist value before i check if its null or not

I currently have a ComboBox which is populated with Artist names and I need to bind it to another comboBox of albums once the Artist is selected.

These are set up as follows in my view:
XAML

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,81,0,0" Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Artists}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArtist}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,115,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlbums}" Width="120" />


private void initialiseArtists()
{
    MusicDataClassesDataContext dataClasses = new MusicDataClassesDataContext();

    artistList = (from m in dataClasses.tblArtists select m.ArtistName).ToList();
}

public List<String> Artists
{
    get
    {
        return this.artistList;
    }
 }

public List<String> Albums
{
    set
    {
        initialiseAlbums();
    }
    get
    {
        return this.albumList;
    }
}

public string SelectedArtist
{
    set
    {
        this.selectedArtist = value;
        initialiseAlbums();
    }
}


private void initialiseAlbums()
{
    if (selectedArtist != null)
    {
        MusicDataClassesDataContext dataClasses = new MusicDataClassesDataContext();

        var getArtist = dataClasses.tblArtists.FirstOrDefault(band => band.ArtistName==       selectedArtist);
        albumList = (from album in dataClasses.tblAlbums
                     where album.ArtistID == getArtist.ArtistID
                     select album.AlbumName).ToList();

        OnPropertyChanged("Albums");
    }
}



   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));}
```

Comment: Can't you use associative arrays? (I don't know WPF, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: WPF doesn't support binding to properties with no public `get` and `set`. Create these accessors for all properties.

Comment: Which line in the code did you check that SelectedArtist is null ?

Comment: I check that SelectedArtist is null inside initialiseAlbums method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a continuation to this question in this thread and marked it as ansawered
[The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection has some invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751316/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-system-collections-objectmodel-observablec)

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
private List<string> _artists;
public List<string> Artists
{
    get { return _artists; }
    set
    {
        _artists = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Artists");
    }
}

public List<string> Albums
{
    get { return GetAllAlbumsByArtist(SelectedArtist); }
}

private string _selectedArtist;
public string SelectedArtist
{
    get { return _selectedArtist; }
    set
    {
        _selectedArtist= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArtist");
        OnPropertyChanged("Albums");
    }
}

public List<string> GetAllAlbumsByArtist(string artist)
{
    //Write your code to get the album data.
}
```

Then the only thing you have to do in xaml is to bind the ItensSource property of the two combo boxes correctly and set the UpdateSourceTrigger to "PropertyChanged".