# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection has some invalid arguments

Tags: wpf, linq

Can some one please tell me Why is this not possible?  I am new to WPF and Linq
I am trying to select a value from my first combobox and display the related values in my second combobox.

```
private void initializeTransactionTypes()
{
    var getAppCode = applicationVModel.GetAllApplications().FirstOrDefault(apps =>   apps.AppCode == selectedApplication);

    var transTypeList = (from transName in transTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                         where transName.Id == getAppCode.Id
                         select transName.Name).ToList();


    //cast list of string to observ.
    ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel> transTypeObsList =
        new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(transTypeList);

    TransactionTypes = transTypeObsList;

    NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
    // }

    //}
}

// Bind trans type combobox to this
public ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel> TransactionTypes
{
    set
    {
        initializeTransactionTypes();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
    }
    get
    {
        return _transactionType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `transTypeList` is a `List<string>` (assuming `transName.Name` is a string) and you are trying to use it to initialise an `ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>`.

The [constructor for `ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202.aspx) requires a `List<T>` so you need to provide a `List<TransactionTypeViewModel>` instead.

It looks like you just need to change your linq query to:

```
var transTypeList = (from transName in transTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                     where transName.Id == getAppCode.Id
                     select transName).ToList();
```

or alternatively:

```
var transTypeList = transTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                                   .Where(t => t.Id == getAppCode.Id)
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Lee thank you so much this helps.. now I am able to select application and step into my  initializeTransactionTypes() method but my getAppCode is null is my query wrong ?

Comment: @Eda - If `appCode` is null then there are no elements in `applicationVModel.GetAllApplications()` with an `AppCode` equal to `selectedApplication`. `FirstOrDefault` returns null if no matching element was found.

Comment: no matter what I assign to my selectedApplication will not pick up the value after i do a select from the application combo so that i do a compare in the initializeTransactionTypes method
    forexample I gave it "Test"
    public string SelectedApplication
        {
            set
            {
                this.selectedApplication = value;
                initializeTransactionTypes();
            }
        }

Comment: This is the part that returns null:
var getAppCode = applicationVModel.GetAllApplications().Where(apps => apps.Name == selectedApplication).FirstOrDefault();

if I give it a static data for example 
var getAppCode = applicationVModel.GetAllApplications().Where(apps => apps.Name == “Test”).FirstOrDefault(); 
it works as expected but I want to make it dynamic
here is my selectApplication property 

private string selectedApplication;

Comment: private string selectedApplication;
        public string SelectedApplication
        {set{this.selectedApplication = value;
         initializeTransactionTypes();}
            get{return this.selectedApplication;}}

Comment: @Eda - Either `selectedApplication` is not what you expect, or `GetAllApplications()` contains different data than you expect. My advice would be to assign the result of `GetAllApplications()` to a variable, and then attach a debugger and break where you are calling `FirstOrDefault`. Then you can see what the real values are. One thing to be aware of is that `==` does a case-insensitive comparison, so you must ensure name matches exactly.

Comment: I found out that selectApplication is returning the whole class name not the value i just selected from the combo box. my getAllApplication() contains the expected data and "Test" is included in that list.                                solutionName.Viewmodel(folder).ClassName is what is returned from my selectApplication but not "Test"

Comment: here is how my xaml looks like :                                           <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,81" Width="122" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name"   SelectedItem="{Binding Path= SelectedApplication,Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectedValue="{Binding Name}"/>

Comment: I found out what the problem is in the xaml I wasn't assigning selectedvaluePath. Here is the change. Hope it will help someone some day ...                                                 <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,81" Width="122" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name"   SelectedValue="{Binding Path= SelectedApplication,Mode=TwoWay}"
             SelectedValuePath="Name" />

Comment: Hi Lee, Can you help me with this issue that I opened here?                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821322/binding-objects-to-a-tree-structure-xaml?noredirect=1#comment24255508_16821322