# Binding objects to a tree structure xaml

Tags: wpf, binding, tree

I am working on a WPF tree control. My class has objects which are a reference to another object.
I want to be able to bind my objects in this class to be able to be bound to the tree in the xaml.

This is what I have in my ViewModel and I want to bind each to a tree structure :

```
class PerformNewVehicleInquiryModel{
        public List<AddressDataType> AddressDataVMField { get; set; }
        public List<NetworkContolType> NetworkControlVMField { get; set; }
        public List<IdentificationType> VehicleIdentificationVMField { get; set; }
        public List<PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType> PerformNewVehicleInquiryVMRequestField { get; set; }
        }

//here is the method to add data  to each node

    public List<PerformNewVehicleInquiryModel> getAllPerformNewVehicleInquiry()
    {
        // add to addressDataField List
        addressDataField.Add(new AddressDataType("AA", "A1"));
        addressDataField.Add(new AddressDataType("AA", "A1"));

        // add to networkControlField List
        //List<NetworkContolType> networkContolTypeList = new List<NetworkContolType>();
        networkControlField.Add(new NetworkContolType(addressDataField, "22", "1305231128040001 1UNISC"));

        // create and add to identificationType List
        List<IdentificationType> identificationTypeList = new List<IdentificationType>();
        identificationTypeList.Add(new IdentificationType("IdentificationType1"));
        identificationTypeList.Add(new IdentificationType("IdentificationType1"));

        // create and add to PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType List
        PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType performNewVehicleInquiryRequestType = new PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType(networkControlField, identificationTypeList);
        // add to list
        //List<PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType> performNewVehicleInquiryRequestTypeList = new List<PerformNewVehicleInquiryRequestType>();
        performNewVehicleInquiryRequestField.Add(performNewVehicleInquiryRequestType);

        // create and add to PerformNewVehicleInquiryModel
        performNewVehicleInquiryModel.Add(new PerformNewVehicleInquiryModel(addressDataField, networkControlField, identificationTypeList, performNewVehicleInquiryRequestField));

        return performNewVehicleInquiryModel;

    }

      // Bind tree to this observable list
    public ObservableCollection<PerformNewVehicleInquiryViewModel> PerformNewVehicleInquiries
    {
        get { return performNewVehicleInquiry; }
        set
        {
            if (performNewVehicleInquiry == value)
                return;
            performNewVehicleInquiry = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PerformNewVehicleInquiries");
        }
    }

    I am having hard time to bind this to a tree structure.  it wont display the objects populated in the method above.
```

// Here is what my XAML Looks like now

```
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding PerformNewVehicleInquiryVMRequestField}">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding NetworkContolType }" />

                    <!-- NetworkControlVMField template -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkControlVMField}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AddressData}" />

                            <!-- AddressDataVMField template -->
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding AddressDataVMField}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationID}" />

                                    <!-- AddressDataVMField template -->
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageOriginatorID }" />

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        </TreeView>
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: you just use the `ItemSource` property and bind to your model. e.g:   `<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" />`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I already did that as shown in the code sample i posted

Comment: here is what i tried   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PerformNewVehicleInquiries.Items}" Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PerformNewVehicleInquiryViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddressDataVMField}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MessageOriginatorID}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>     </DataTemplate></TreeView.Resources></TreeView>       ....I did this for all four objects